# How to get result string of console.log in javascript code?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I enter `$("p")` in the chrome console, I get `[<p>Text1</p>,<p>..</p>]` , which is just what I want. Now I want to store the result string to a variable and reuse it later, but i couldn't find a way yet ( `$("p").toString()` gets `[Object Object]`).

Is there a way to get the result string of `console.log` in code?

Comment: Why would you want that string? Just for debugging purposes? Would `JSON.stringify` come close?

Comment: I want to use it in my blog: the first line is the code, the second line is a button. After i click the button, the console string of the code appears below. Since there may be many jquery operations, it will be better than open the console, find the specific line , go back to the page and find its corresponding operation.

Comment: If you're doing JS development, that console should be permanently open, right? So I suppose I don't get the use case...

Comment: You are right. But i want every blog visitor will see the result, and i don't think everyone will open the console, and append result under the code is more visual.

Comment: console.log is not standard.  What browser/environment are you trying to replicate?

Comment: @cameron Yeah there is no "standard" way to render an array of DOM elements succinctly as a string. Each browser likely will do that differently anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about the browser behavior

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `console.log` does some magic that a string cant do.  It doesn't just render the object as a string. It also make the object structure interactive and clickable.  It's rendering multiple interactive elements.  The dev panel is taking a reference to an object and rendering it outside of where you code can reach.

But as @minitech notes, you can get close with `JSON.stringify(myObject)`.

```
var myObject = { a: 1, b: 2 };
myObject.toString();      // [object Object]
JSON.stringify(myObject); // {"a":1,"b":2}
```

Though this won't work with DOM elements, as they typically have circular references.  So you'd have to write your own function to crawl a jQuery object and dump it to a string.  There isn't anything built in to do it for you.

Comment: I got it.Thanks. PS: i didn't vote against the answer. Someone else does.

Answer (score 3):

Well, here’s something-ish:

```
function repr(obj) {
    if(obj == null || typeof obj === 'string' || typeof obj === 'number') return String(obj);
    if(obj.length) return '[' + Array.prototype.map.call(obj, repr).join(', ') + ']';
    if(obj instanceof HTMLElement) return '<' + obj.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '>';
    if(obj instanceof Text) return '"' + obj.nodeValue + '"';
    if(obj.toString) return obj.toString();

    return String(obj);
}
```

It isn’t interactive or comprehensive. If you need that, I can add it, but at a certain point it might just be easier to look at the WebKit developer tools’ source :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [util-inspect](https://github.com/Automattic/util-inspect)

> This is an extraction of Node's `inspect` utility from the `util` module, with two fundamental advantages:
>
> - Single, focused module
> - Compatible with all browsers and environments.

Although it is compatible with browsers, it uses CommonJS so needs to be bundled first. But there's a fork that you can load directly in a browser via [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/browser-util-inspect@0.2.0/index.js).